# Sapper is not reloading data when hitting link

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sapper

I’m building a site using sapper and requesting data from an API. It has been working smooth until now.

When I’m going from site.com/title/id1 to site.com/title/id2 the new information is not loaded until I hit a manual refresh. Any ideas?

```
import { stores, goto } from "@sapper/app";
import Card from "../_titlecard.svelte";

const { page } = stores();
const { slug } = $page.params;

import { onMount } from "svelte";
let looper = [];
let artistName = "";
let titleName = "";
let dvdCover = "";
let titleCover = "";
let genre = "";
let tracks = [];
onMount(async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://.com/api/title/${slug}`);

  const data = await res.json();

  artistName = data.artistName;
  titleName = data.name;
  dvdCover = data.graphics.dvd;
  titleCover = data.graphics.landscape;
  genre = data.genre;
  tracks = data.tracks.length;

  const res2 = await fetch(`https://.com/api/artists/all`);
  const data2 = await res2.json();

  let moreTitles = [];
  const more = data2.map((x) => {
    if (x.titles.length > 0 && x.genre === genre) {
      looper.push(x.titles[0]);

      looper = moreTitles;
    }
  });
});
```

And then I have this in the html

```
{#each looper.slice(0, 4) as item, i} 
  <Card imgurl={item.graphics.dvd} concert={item.name} id={item.id} />
{/each}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A page component is not unmounted and mounted again if the navigation results in the same page component being used, so your `onMount` will only be run once with the first `id`.

You could use a [reactive statement](https://svelte.dev/docs#3_$_marks_a_statement_as_reactive) to make sure you run the desired code every time `$page.params.slug` changes.

**Example**

```js
import { stores, goto } from "@sapper/app";
import Card from "../_titlecard.svelte";
const { page } = stores();

let looper = [];
let artistName = "";
let titleName = "";
let dvdCover = "";
let titleCover = "";
let genre = "";
let tracks = [];

$: (async () => {
  const { slug } = $page.params;

  const res = await fetch(`https://.com/api/title/${slug}`);
  const data = await res.json();

  artistName = data.artistName;
  titleName = data.name;
  dvdCover = data.graphics.dvd;
  titleCover = data.graphics.landscape;
  genre = data.genre;
  tracks = data.tracks.length;

  const res2 = await fetch(`https://.com/api/artists/all`);
  const data2 = await res2.json();

  let moreTitles = [];
  data2.forEach((x) => {
    if (x.titles.length > 0 && x.genre === genre) {
      moreTitles.push(x.titles[0]);
    }
  });

  looper = moreTitles;
})();
```

Comment: Now it is reloading the data which is great, but get warnings like this:UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)

Comment: @blytung That's frustrating. That could happen for a number of different reasons. You can wrap the entire reactive statement body in a try/catch and log the error to see what happened. `try { /* reactive statement body */ } catch (error) { console.log(error); }`